# Is Google App Engine using Documents List API?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-api

I received notifications from google what is about closed any API services.

http://googleappsupdates.blogspot.jp/2015/03/final-reminder-deprecated-google-apps.html

But I don't know that Google App Engine has target APIs. And I'm using package of 'com.google.appengine.api.files'.

I would like to know this...

- Is the 'com.google.appengine.api.files' package closed target?

Comment: What makes you think that an appengine file library is related with the docsList api?

Comment: A...DocsList is not api. It's a service in GoogleAppsScript. I get it. Thanks.

Comment: I was confused with this too at the beginning, I tended to think all google services (apps script, app engine, API, etc) where all conected and interchangeable. Even tough yourself asked it, you can make an answer for future google drops.

Comment: DocsList IS an API. It just jas nothing to do with the java appengine filesysten api.

Comment: @Kriggs Thanks, I asked it myself again.

Comment: @ZigMandel I wanna mean is REST or not REST. Thanks your help so much.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are using?

[Google App Engine Java API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/files/package-summary)

That page does state:

> This api has been deprecated in favor of the App Engine GCS client.

You need to switch to this:

[Interface GcsService](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/javadoc/com/google/appengine/tools/cloudstorage/GcsService)

Also see:

[Google Cloud Service Client](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlecloudstorageclient/)

As far as a "sunset" target date, I couldn't find anything.